# Cross origin requests failing on Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, heroku, cors, preflight

I have a webapp divided into two apps: an API built with Spring (4.2.3) and a front built with AngularJS (1.3.19). The two apps aren’t on the same server so I am struggling with cross origin requests. When the app is using simple requests like a GET on /articles, no problem. When the app is using preflighted requests like POST /articles with a JSON body, I have a 403 on the OPTIONS request that check if the POST is possible.

web.xml :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.clacsy.api.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

CORSFilter.java :

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)  throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Request headers :

- Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
- Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
- Origin:http://localhost:9001

Response :

- Request Method:OPTIONS
- Status Code:403 Forbidden

Response headers :

- Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, content-type
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9001

I have also tried with * for the values of the three Access-Control-Allow-X but still the same problem. I’m facing this problem on Chrome and Firefox. On Safari, I have a 403 but the POST is done anyway.

All the answers to this problem I have found on the Internet didn’t help me. I don’t know why the OPTIONS request is sending back 403, it seems to me that all the Access Control headers are set to the right values.

Thanks in advance for helping me with that problem I am facing for several days.

**[Update]** if I make the call from AngularJS app on localhost:9000 to my API on localhost:8080, it's working! But when I make the call from localhost:9000 to my API hosted on Heroku it's not. Is Heroku blocking something?

Comment: Do you have any security implementation?

Comment: I had spring security enabled but I disabled it and I still have the same problem.